# Save image to firebase as image/jpeg using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to upload pictures to firebase with a mime type of image/jpeg but for some reason they all upload as application/octet-stream.

Heres my code snippet:

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("ProfilePictures/\(image).jpg")
        if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.pickedImage!, 0.5){
            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:{ (metadata, error) in })
```

I got the image through a picker from the photo gallery

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {

        ImageButton.setBackgroundImage(editedImage, for: .normal)
        ImageButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        self.pickedImage = editedImage
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the metadata for the same.

Try it.

metadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg'};

Answer (score 0):

```
let imageNode = storageRef.child("imagePath/\(UUID().uuidString)")
let metaData = StorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"
imageNode.putData(data, metadata: metaData) { (_, _) in
}
```

explanation:

if we upload file data without any meta data, it will recognise it as an application/octet-stream. because of data's unknown format or (missing extension), it saved as binary file which is octet-stream file.

Given that, specify file or data type we need to define its contentType. We can do it by assigning Media type, which is also known as **MIME Protocol**.

some of the Common **MIME types**:

| Extension | MIME Type |
| --- | --- |
| .gif | image/gif |
| .html | text/html |
| .jpg or .jpeg | image/jpeg |
| .mp4 | video/mp4 |

for list of MIME extension [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).
plus as per this link **application/octet-stream** is the default value for media type.

Swift part:

as for using firebase storage from swift, we can assign meta data using StorageMetadata class. Firebase's putData method has optional parameter metaData of type **StorageMetadata**

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?